# How to excute pipe after excuting method and store data in BehaviorSubject in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making an angular project and trying to create a translate pipe, where I will store the translations in the database, and I will create a BehaviorSubject in a service that call backend api to store all translations in this BehaviorSubject and I will subscribe on it, reading from it in the pipe instead of calling backend api every once in a while .
The problem is that when I call the method inside the server that loads the store translation in the BehaviorSubject, I call it inside the ngOnInit in the app.Component, before it finishes executing, it calls the pipe, so the BehaviorSubject still has no data, so it won't work. I need pipe wait till I fill data in BehaviorSubject

Comment: Please add more details to the question with some code/pseudo code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Inside the switchMap operator you define a function that checks if translations are available in BehaviorSubject. If no translations are available, the function calls the asynchronous function loadTranslations(), which fetches translations from the backend and stores them in BehaviorSubject. The map function then returns the processed data. If translations are already available, the function returns a data stream with the processed data using the of operator.

```
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private translations: any;

  constructor(private readonly myTranslationService: MyTranslationService) {}

  transform(value: string): any {
    return this.myTranslationService.translations$.pipe(
      switchMap((translations) => {
        if (!translations) {
          return this.myTranslationService.loadTranslations().pipe(
            map(() => {
              return this.myTranslationService.getTranslations()[value] || value;
            })
          );
        } else {
          return of(translations[value] || value);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```